# how to provide access to PublicClientApplicationBuilder AcquireTokenInteractive from Azure app service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-msal

I have a Blazor (ASP.Net Core) application that runs on Azure app service.

I have a working solution with MSAL fetching and caching tokens on my local machine.

When publishing to Azure app service I get an access denied error when using http://localhost as redirectURL

```
HttpListenerException: Access is denied.
System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
```

It seems like MSAL cant find an open port for the communication. How can I solve this problem?

Here is the C# code producing the error

```
    IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(appClientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUrl)                    
                .Build();

            TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(app.UserTokenCache);

            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {                                
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopesList, firstAccount)
                                      .ExecuteAsync();             
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
              try
                {            
>----------  THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS ---------------<        
                    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopesList)                        
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }                    
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError("GetTokenPublic() Error acquiring Token {ex}", ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogDebug("GetTokenPublic() Error acquiring token silently {ex}", ex);
                return false;
            }
```

Input is

```
 scopes = "openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read.Shared"

 redirectURL = "http://localhost"
```

Full error code

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.DefaultOSBrowser.HttpListenerInterceptor.ListenToSingleRequestAndRespondAsync(Int32 port, Func`2 responseProducer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.InterceptAuthorizationUriAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.AcquireAuthorizationAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, RequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceInternalAsync(IWebUI webUi, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceVerifierAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.GetTokenResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenInteractiveParameters interactiveParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MinServiceAssistent.Data.GraphService.GetTokenPublic() in C:\Michael\blazor_repository\MinServiceAssistent\Data\GraphService.cs:line 182
   at MinServiceAssistent.Data.GraphService.Initialize(String userId) in C:\Michael\blazor_repository\MinServiceAssistent\Data\GraphService.cs:line 61
   at MinServiceAssistent.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.OutlookIntegrationModel.OnPostConnectToAzureAsync() in C:\Michael\blazor_repository\MinServiceAssistent\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\OutlookIntegration.cshtml.cs:line 80
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert[T](Object taskAsObject)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

**UPDATE - SOLVED/RE-IMPLEMENTED**

I've solved the issue by using a ConfidentialClientApplication in stead of a PublicApplication. The only thing I had to change was to fetch the authorization code manually using:

```
string url =
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" +
            "client_id=" + appClientId +
            "&response_type=code" +
            "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl +
            "&response_mode=query" +
            "&scope=" + appScopes +
            "&state=12345";
```

When receiving the authorization code I use AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode and store the token in my TokenCache and voila :-)

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(appClientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUrl)
                .WithClientSecret(appClientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
                .WithLogging(Log, Microsoft.Identity.Client.LogLevel.Info, true)
                .Build();

TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(app.UserTokenCache);

authResult = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopesList, authorizationCode).ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: What port are you listening on?

Comment: I don't know. The MSAL automatically searches for an open port, I've also tried 443, but with the same result. Also, I'm not completely sure it's a port issue!

Comment: Can you update the error code in the post?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the wrong line of code, not the error message.

Comment: You can replace the redirecturi with `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net`. And try again. For more details, you can [refer to this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications#initializing-a-confidential-client-application-from-code).

Comment: I already tried that and get this error message
GetTokenPublic() Error acquiring Token MSAL.NetCore.4.22.0.0.MsalClientException: 
 ErrorCode: loopback_redirect_uri
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but https://teamfokusappservice-test.azurewebsites.net/ was found. Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication object. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe I can't using the MSAL AquireTokenInteractively on a webpage/webapp. The PublicClientApplication is not for web apps (Class to be used to acquire tokens in desktop or mobile applications )
   It probably works locally because it can access the localhost OS browser, as it were a desktop app. Guess I need to implement my access to Graph in another way. Unfortunately the ConfidentialClientApp doesn't provide a AquireTokenInteractively!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to re-implement. See description in original post.